# POST request to TestFlight Api failing with 500

Tags: c#, http-post, testflight

I'm trying to upload file vie a POST request to [TestFlight Api](https://testflightapp.com/api/doc/). I try to do it as simplest as possible, but I'm still getting Error 500.

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest
    .Create('http://testflightapp.com/api/builds.json') as HttpWebRequest;
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.Headers.Add("api_token", "####");
request.Headers.Add("team_token", "####");
request.Headers.Add("notes", "notes");
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
byte[] messageArray = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
request.ContentLength = messageArray.Length;
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(messageArray, 0, messageArray.Length);
requestStream.Close();

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string result = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
responseReader.Close();
response.Close();
return result;
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please avoid using tags in title (I tried to edit it into readable title) and "thank you notes". Feel free to discuss on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the way to programmatically build a multipart form. You are mixing headers and content, not following the proper multipart separators, not even naming the parts, incorrectly computing the content length, etc. See [c# multipart/form-data submit programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035229/c-sharp-multipart-form-data-submit-programmatically) for help in csharp.

You may want to use the higher level csharp constructs ([like MultipartFormDataContent if you have .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload)). In Java, one ends up with: https://github.com/jenkinsci/testflight-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/testflight/TestflightUploader.java.

If you want to do it on your own, I really advise you to for example, use curl to make the uploads and wiresharp to extract the TCP conversation and compare what curl is doing what we you do.

Answer (score 0):

1 Looks like youre missing Header with name **file**  this is also required

https://testflightapp.com/api/doc/#

2 contenttype

```
webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
```

3 extra settings?

maybe you should also set request.UserAgent and/or request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering

```
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";

request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
```

Comment: I have added "request.Headers.Add("file", "@appName.ipa");" but the same result..

Comment: Well, after your 3-step update, I have moved forward, now I'm getting error 400, bad request.