# REST POST with parameters and a .csv

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, http-post

We recently signed up with a survey provider to send out surveys. They have a REST API to import a .csv file with contacts

I had a look at their [documentation](https://survey.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/ControlPanel/docs.php#importPanel_2.5) under "importPanel". I can successfully use this to create a new panel (mailing list) but fail to post the csv with the request using a rest test client

I then had a look [here](http://support.qualtrics.com/survey-platform/developer-tools/api-integration/common-api-use-cases#SurveyPlatform) where it says "URL: If present, the Qualtrics API will attempt to load the CSV file from the URL specified; otherwise, **it simply looks at the POST for the data.**" is anyone able to explain to me what this means? If I need to provide ~10 required parameters how would it "simply" find the file in the post?

I asked this in a support ticket and what I got back was a `php` snippet:

```
<?php
$baseURL = "https://clientname.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/ControlPanel/api.php";
// full path to file you want to include in post
$filePath_panel = "/path/to/panel_data.csv";
$cURL = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $baseURL);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 43);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// all options being used, including User, Token, etc.
$options = array(
// insert/update options here
"Request"   => "importPanel",
"User"  => "",
"Token" => "",
"Format"    => "JSON",
"Version"   => "2.2",
"LibraryID" => "",
"Name"  => "",
"ColumnHeaders" => ,
"Email" => ,
"FirstName" => ,
"LastName"  => ,
"Language"  => ,
"AllED" => ,
);
// add file to POST
$options['file'] = "@$filePath_panel";
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $options);
$results = curl_exec($cURL);
$info = curl_getinfo($cURL);
?>
```

I'm looking at various ways to do this with C# but not sure where to start, should I use `HttpClient` or `WebRequest` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you'll start with generating the request manually (via fiddler or other tool), and once you get it through from there, it will be easier to transform to code.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your php code, these options are set as POST data.

If content is not multipart (and I don't see it being set anywhere on the request), the POST content is encoded in the body as a query string, something like this:

```
var1=value&var2=value&var3=value
```

It's important to url encode the values (special chars replaced with %XX) to not break the query sequence.

Anyway, I would recomend not to use WebClient nor HttpClient directly, use some REST framework like RestSharp (http://restsharp.org/) as it will simplify a lot your work.

Cheers.

Comment: Reading the php docs I see "CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data."  I already tried URL encode required parameters in the body as a query string like "Request=importPanel&User=xxx&Token=xxx&LibraryID=xxx&Version=2.5&Format=JSON&Name=Testing1..." and seems like there's no "FileContent" (or similiar) variable so how would it know what's csv data? I replied to the support ticket and asked more questions.

Comment: If it's multipart then the encoding is different, this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035229/c-sharp-multipart-form-data-submit-programmatically can help you, but again, if you use RestSharp it will do it automatically if you set the content as multipart

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out RestSharp and come back